# How to generate a number pattern with given start and end value?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, integer

How can i generate a number pattern like this using php?

```
a. Start = 1, End = 3
    123
    231
    312
b. Start = 2 , End = 7
    234567
    345672
    456723
    567234
    672345
    723456
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried this code:

```php
function generate (int $start, int $end)
{
    $arr = [];
    for($start; $start <= $end; $start ++) {
        $arr[] = $start;
    }
    for($i = $arr[0]; $i <= count($arr); $i++) {
        for($l = $i - 1; $l < $end; $l ++) {
            echo $arr[$l];
        }
        echo " -> $i<br/>";
    }
}
```

and get this output:

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

But how to show the rest numbers?

Comment: @AzizFebriyanto There are a lot of ways to achieve this. But before attempting this, learn about looping inside 1D and 2D arrays, swapping 2 different indices in an array etc. That can give you a good start for this.

Comment: @nice_dev i tried the edited code, and still don't found the answer, please help me improve the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this algorithm:

```js
const generate = (start, end) => {
    const length = end-start+1 
    let array = Array.from({length}, () => Array.from({length}, (x,i)=>i+start)) // creating 2D array and filling it with a loop from start value to end value
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        poped = array[i].splice(i); // slice and put the element from index i to the last index 
        array[i].unshift(...poped) // adding poped value to the begining of the array
    }
    return array 
}

console.log(generate(1,3))
console.log(generate(2,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

How to think?

Before you code, understand what is asked and try to verbalize in plain language, say English. The pattern you have simply says "rotate me left" or "Take first digit. Put it at the end. Add it to output. Keep doing so till you get unique numbers". Now that we understand what to do, you have to make computer understand how to do it.

After the above explanation, I don't feel the need to add the code. You can try it yourself as I don't want to rob the fun of doing something by yourself. Whichever language that is, Create a string of all numbers from `start` to `end` -> Erase at begin of string -> Append -> Add to output.

Tricky case (not really) is when the `start` and `end` are not single digit. I leave that to you as an exercise. (Hint: Delimiters can help.)